# CSS: Freezing the header row in a table is showing the first row below it

Tags: css, html

I have a two tabs in a page and each of the tabs has a table.  When scrolling down the page the tab names and the table headers were also scrolling up.  To handle this I made a few changes in the css file the tab header and the table headers are freezed the data is getting overlapped.

1) The first row of the table is shown under the table header.
2) While scrolling up the data is overlapping the tab names and the table headers, is there any way of stopping the transparency>

```css
body {
background: Lavender;
font-family: sans-serif;
}   

.wrapper { 
background: white;
margin-top: 7em;
margin-right: 3em;
margin-left: 3em;
padding: 1em;
width: 90%;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
}

.tabs{
position: fixed;
}

ul.tabs {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul.tabs li {
border: gray solid 1px;
border-bottom: none;
float: left;
margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
padding: .25em .5em;
}

ul.tabs li a {
color: gray;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
background: gray;
}

ul.tabs li.active a {
color: white;
}

.clr {
clear: both;
}

article {
border-top: gray solid 1px;
padding: 0 1em;
margin-top: 1.8em;
}

table {
border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: 0;
}

td, th { 
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

table tr:hover td {
background: #F7FE2E;
}

#adjustment_tab th { 
background-color: lightgray;
padding: .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#adjustment_tab td { 
padding: .1em 0em 0em .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#discount_tab th { 
background-color: lightgray;
padding: .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#discount_tab td { 
padding: .1em 0em 0em .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#tariff_tab th { 
background-color: lightgray;
padding: .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#tariff_tab td { 
padding: .1em 0em 0em .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#product_tab th { 
background-color: lightgray;
padding: .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#product_tab td { 
padding: .1em 0em 0em .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#event_tab th { 
background-color: lightgray;
padding: .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#event_tab td { 
padding: .1em 0em 0em .5em;
text-align: left;
}
#customersegment_tab th { 
background-color: lightgray;
padding: .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#customersegment_tab td { 
padding: .1em 0em 0em .5em;
text-align: left;
}

#header {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
background: lavender;
width: 77em;
height: 6em;
margin-left: 3em;
margin-right: 3em;
padding-top: 1em;
clear: both;
}

#header p  h1 { margin: 0; }

.align-left {
float: left;
}

.align-right {
float: right;
}

.code {
width: 50px;
}

thead
{
position: fixed;
}
tbody
{
position: relative;
padding-top: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Configure GL Codes</title>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/gl_code.js"></script>
<style> @import url("stylesheets/gl_code.css");</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<img class="align-left" src="images/asdf2.png" alt="Varun Logo" width="237" height="45">
<p class="align-right">You are logged in as Nitin&nbsp;<a href="GLSignout">Signout</a></p>
<h1>GL Codes</h1>
</div>
<section class="wrapper">
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="#adjustment_tab">GL Adjustment Map</a></li>
<li><a href="#discount_tab">GL Discount Map</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clr"></div>
<section class="block">
<article id="adjustment_tab">
<br>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sr, No.</th>
<th>ACCOUNT CODE</th>
<th>PRODUCT NAME</th>
<th>PRODUCT CODE</th>
<th>CHANNEL CODE</th>
<th>MODIFY</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="Electronic Recharge for XYX Ajel"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="others"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="Electronic Recharge for XYX Ajel"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="others"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420150"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="adjustment"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240200"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420600"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="adjustment"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240200"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="Electronic Recharge for XYX Ajel"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420400"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="adjustment"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240200"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710350"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="Electronic Recharge for XYX Ajel"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="adjustment"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240200"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="Electronic Recharge for XYX Ajel"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="others"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>13</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="others"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="Electronic Recharge for XYX Ajel"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="Electronic Recharge for XYX Ajel"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>16</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="Electronic Recharge for XYX Ajel"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>17</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="others"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>18</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="Electronic Recharge for XYX Ajel"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>19</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="others"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>20</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420150"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="adj_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="adjustment"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240200"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="adj_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button ADJUSTMENT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</article>
<article id="discount_tab">
<br>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sr, No.</th>
<th>ACCOUNT CODE</th>
<th>PRODUCT NAME</th>
<th>PRODUCT CODE</th>
<th>CHANNEL CODE</th>
<th>MODIFY</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>13</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>16</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>17</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>18</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>19</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value=""></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>20</td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_acccode_n" maxlength="6" value="420650"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input" type="text" name="disc_prodname_n" maxlength="100" value="Others"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_prodcode_n" maxlength="6" value="240010"></td>
<td><input class="gl_input code" type="text" name="disc_channelcode_n" maxlength="6" value="710300"></td>
<td><button class="modify_button DISCOUNT" >Modify</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</section>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```